# How to set an action to unpublish content containing some particular keywords?

Tags: 8, actions

I just enabled `action module` provided by Drupal core. There in configuration, I have chosen **CREATE AN ADVANCED ACTION**, and then choose **"unpublish content containing keywords**". I have entered keywords separated by comma but content still not get unpublished.[image]

How this will work?

**Note**: I haven't added any custom functionality, nor did I use any contributed module. It's the default feature provided by Drupal core. I just enabled Actions module from the module list. My current version of Drupal is 8.2.4.

Comment: I haven't added any custom functionality, nor I used any contrib module. Its the default feature provided by core. I just enabled Actions module from the module list. My current version of Drupal is 8.2.4.

Comment: Please I didn't understand the reason of removing all comments? Also down-voted this question.

Comment: use [simplytest.me](http://simplytest.me) and type "Drupal core" and do some testing there to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am having same issue. I am starting to think that I need to create simple modules in order to fire those events. But that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @NoSssweat I tested as per your suggestion. https://dcx0n.ply.st/node/1 And can confirm it doesn't unpublish the content, nor the comment. Admin: user: admin, pass: admin